# Is SNI possible in Tomcat without the Tomcat Native Library?

Tags: tomcat9, sni

Is it possible to use [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) in [Tomcat 9](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/) without installing the [Tomcat Native Library](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/)?

I reviewed the Tomcat 9 configuration documentation and it's not clear if the JSSE Java SSL implementation would be sufficient or if the OpenSSL implementation can be accessed through the existing pure Java code without the native connector.

Thanks.

**Update: With Mark Thomas's reassurance, I got the code to work. It's awesome! Thanks Mark! Here is my code in part, hopefully it can help others:**

```
        Connector c = tomcat.getConnector();
        c.setPort(8443);
        c.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", "true");
        c.setAttribute("defaultSSLHostConfigName", "www.domain1.com");
        SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig1 = new SSLHostConfig();
        sslHostConfig1.setHostName("www.domain1.com");
        sslHostConfig1.setCertificateFile("/certs/domain1.pem");
        c.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig1);
        SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig2 = new SSLHostConfig();
        sslHostConfig2.setHostName("www.domain2.com");
        sslHostConfig2.setCertificateFile("/certs/domain2.pem");
        c.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig2);
        SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig3 = new SSLHostConfig();
        sslHostConfig3.setHostName("*.domain3.com");
        sslHostConfig3.setCertificateFile("/certs/domain3-wildcard.pem");
        c.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig3);
```

Comment: Add your answer as an answer really, instead of editing the question. Also please try  to obfuscate names using RFC 2606 that is basically `example.com` and not other made up names (you can use as well the `.example` TLD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSSE implementation supports SNI (we had to hand craft it).

If you want to use the OpenSSL implementation, you have to use Tomcat Native.

Comment: Thanks! I am using embedded Tomcat and for some reason couldn't get it to work. I will ask a separate question and post my code.

Comment: I got this to work (see update) - thank you so much. However I had a follow-up question which I posted separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997242/embedded-tomcat-update-delete-certificates-without-restarting