# Embedded Tomcat - update/delete certificates without restarting

Tags: ssl, tomcat9, sni

I am using embedded Tomcat and using `SSLHostConfig` to add SNI certificates when I create the connector. It works wonderfully.

I am also able to add certificates without restarting Tomcat using something like this:

```
SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig = new SSLHostConfig();
sslHostConfig2.setHostName(host);
sslHostConfig2.setCertificateFile(path);
connector.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig);
```

This also works perfectly.

Also, without restarting Tomcat, I can get a list of all the existing `SSLHostConfig` instances using this:

```
SSLHostConfig[] sslHostConfigs = connector.findSslHostConfigs();
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to update or delete an existing `SSLHostConfig` instance. Setting it to null in the array doesn't work. Also, replacing it in the array with a new `SSLHostConfig` instance doesn't work either.

Is there a way to delete or modify an `SSLHostConfig` instance without restarting Tomcat?

Thanks.

Comment: `connector.removeSslHostConfig(host)`? Based on what I see in https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/86e7dbf52075c41a94562a1765efa314cd261e88

Comment: Indeed, the commit, while being done on Set 15, 2017!, is tagged with "9.0.26" (but not sure if it is really merged in this version, it is tagged with all previous versions too). So besides waiting for new release, you can also patch a local copy with it to have it before. Or you could be a betatester of this new version, and test it specifically for this exact feature you need, I am sure the developers will be happy if you report any problems. Or write a subclass of current class of connector, to get access to its inner sslHostConfigs variable, if possible. PS: I know nothing about Tomcat.

Comment: I would still suggest you make extra sure that specific commit is included in that release, and even better test the release yourself on some test environment of yours before it goes live for true, so that you can both assess in fact that the feature you need is included and works the way you need it to work.

Comment: That method is available in all Tomcat 9.0.x releases from 9.0.0 onwards.

Comment: @MarkThomas - if you don't mind, could you answer the original question? Thank you so much!

Comment: @MarkThomas - never mind, I found the answer and posted it. I know you are very busy and thank you so much for all the great work you are doing in the Tomcat project!

Answer (score 0):

To update an SSLHostConfig with a new certificate file (which was referenced when creating it originally), this works:

```
    Http11NioProtocol protocol (Http11NioProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler();
    protocol.reloadSslHostConfig(host);
```

Of course this assumes that you are using the Http11NioProtocol as the protocol handler for your connector.